# How can I use List<object> with Integer and Float ?in java

Tags: java, list

In fact, I want to use "normOfVector()" method with Integer, and Float, but I couldn't

I get this error:

The method normOfVector(ArrayList) in the type TestMethod is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

```
    package code;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestMethod
{

    public static float normOfVector(ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        float sum = 0.0f;
        for (Integer i : list)
            sum = sum + (float) (i * i);
        // end for

        return (float) Math.sqrt(sum);
    }// end function


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // In this case no Problem
        ArrayList<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<>();
        listI.add(0);
        listI.add(3);
        listI.add(5);
        listI.add(7);
        listI.add(2);
        float result = normOfVector(listI);

        // In this case will not work
        ArrayList<Float> listF = new ArrayList<>();
        listF.add(0.0f);
        listF.add(3.0f);
        listF.add(5.0f);
        listF.add(7.0f);
        listF.add(2.0f);
        result = normOfVector(listF);

    }// end main

}// end class
```

My point is:

I want to create a method that accept the two cases.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can actually run?

Comment: I would use `List<Double>` as every possible `int` and `float` will fit into a `double` without loss of precision.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @محمدالتويجري what do you mean "doesn't work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first block your are computing numbers but storing them as objects.  You should be storing them as `Integer` or `Float`, or maybe `Double` or `Number`, but not `Object`.  Second in your `cos(...)` method you should limit what kind of parameters are accepted by changing the declaration to `List<Integer>`, `List<Float>` or `List<? extends Number>`.  It may help to study up on [java generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) and especially using the [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) [principle](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/java-generics-tutorial-part-iii.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated code.

```
public class TestMethod {

    public static double normOfVector(List<? extends Number> list) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (Number d : list)
            sum += d.doubleValue() * d.doubleValue();

        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<>();
        listI.add(0);
        listI.add(3);
        listI.add(5);
        listI.add(7);
        listI.add(2);
        double result = normOfVector(listI);

        List<Float> listF = new ArrayList<>();
        listF.add(0.0f);
        listF.add(3.0f);
        listF.add(5.0f);
        listF.add(7.0f);
        listF.add(2.0f);
        result = normOfVector(listF);
    }
}
```

---

This is how I would write it using `List<Double>`

```
Map<String, Double> currentWord = new HashMap<>();
double first = main.getWords().get(firstWord);
for(Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : main.getWords()) {
    String secondWord = entry.getValue();
    double cosValue = vectors.cos(first, entry.getValue());
    if (cosValue >= percentage) {
        currentWord.put(secondWord, Math.round(cosValue * 100) / 100.0);
        break; // is there any point searching for another word?
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this idea. I tried to avoid hash map for another reasons that related to another part of my code.

Comment: @محمدالتويجري why do you have to use `Integer` and `Float` but not `Double`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also use something like this:

```
Number[] numbers = new Number[] { valueOfFloat, valueOfInteger };
```